# copy files from android core prime to mint 18.1

Tags: linux-mint, android, samsung

I have a samsung core prime and mint 18.1 and I'm trying to copy pictures from my phone and SD card to my computer, when I plugged it in the folders with pictures are there but i can't open them or move them, It froze my entire computer until I unplugged it. How do I do transfer my stuff?

Edit: When I tried switching it to ptp mode it showed me my pictures in the folders but i still couldn't move them, it said i had 2 samsungs and showed them as cameras on desktop. I installed and tried gmtp but it crashed when i tried to connect my phone

Comment: A Unix way (not mint or ubuntu or arch specific) would be using a command line utility called 'adb' (Android Debug Bridge). Are you willing to try it or would you rather stick to a graphical interface?

Comment: @VincentAchard I'd prefer a graphical one if you have a way :)